# File name grouping and indexing

Tags: python

I have a folder with txt files like below,

[image]

and I have used `os.listdir` to generate a file list,

```
['acc_exp01_user01.txt', 'acc_exp02_user01.txt', 'acc_exp03_user02.txt', 'acc_exp04_user02.txt', 'acc_exp05_user03.txt', 'acc_exp06_user03.txt', 'acc_exp07_user04.txt', 'acc_exp08_user04.txt', 'acc_exp09_user05.txt', 'acc_exp10_user05.txt', 'acc_exp11_user06.txt', 'acc_exp12_user06.txt', 'acc_exp13_user07.txt', 'acc_exp14_user07.txt', 'acc_exp15_user08.txt', 'acc_exp16_user08.txt', 'acc_exp17_user09.txt', 'acc_exp18_user09.txt', 'acc_exp19_user10.txt', 'acc_exp20_user10.txt', 'acc_exp21_user10.txt', 'acc_exp22_user11.txt', 'acc_exp23_user11.txt', 'acc_exp24_user12.txt', 'acc_exp25_user12.txt', 'acc_exp26_user13.txt', 'acc_exp27_user13.txt', 'acc_exp28_user14.txt', 'acc_exp29_user14.txt', 'acc_exp30_user15.txt', 'acc_exp31_user15.txt', 'acc_exp32_user16.txt', 'acc_exp33_user16.txt', 'acc_exp34_user17.txt', 'acc_exp35_user17.txt', 'acc_exp36_user18.txt', 'acc_exp37_user18.txt', 'acc_exp38_user19.txt', 'acc_exp39_user19.txt', 'acc_exp40_user20.txt', 'acc_exp41_user20.txt', 'acc_exp42_user21.txt', 'acc_exp43_user21.txt', 'acc_exp44_user22.txt', 'acc_exp45_user22.txt', 'acc_exp46_user23.txt', 'acc_exp47_user23.txt', 'acc_exp48_user24.txt', 'acc_exp49_user24.txt', 'acc_exp50_user25.txt', 'acc_exp51_user25.txt', 'acc_exp52_user26.txt', 'acc_exp53_user26.txt', 'acc_exp54_user27.txt', 'acc_exp55_user27.txt', 'acc_exp56_user28.txt', 'acc_exp57_user28.txt', 'acc_exp58_user29.txt', 'acc_exp59_user29.txt', 'acc_exp60_user30.txt', 'acc_exp61_user30.txt', 'gyro_exp01_user01.txt', 'gyro_exp02_user01.txt', 'gyro_exp03_user02.txt', 'gyro_exp04_user02.txt', 'gyro_exp05_user03.txt', 'gyro_exp06_user03.txt', 'gyro_exp07_user04.txt', 'gyro_exp08_user04.txt', 'gyro_exp09_user05.txt', 'gyro_exp10_user05.txt', 'gyro_exp11_user06.txt', 'gyro_exp12_user06.txt', 'gyro_exp13_user07.txt', 'gyro_exp14_user07.txt', 'gyro_exp15_user08.txt', 'gyro_exp16_user08.txt', 'gyro_exp17_user09.txt', 'gyro_exp18_user09.txt', 'gyro_exp19_user10.txt', 'gyro_exp20_user10.txt', 'gyro_exp21_user10.txt', 'gyro_exp22_user11.txt', 'gyro_exp23_user11.txt', 'gyro_exp24_user12.txt', 'gyro_exp25_user12.txt', 'gyro_exp26_user13.txt', 'gyro_exp27_user13.txt', 'gyro_exp28_user14.txt', 'gyro_exp29_user14.txt', 'gyro_exp30_user15.txt', 'gyro_exp31_user15.txt', 'gyro_exp32_user16.txt', 'gyro_exp33_user16.txt', 'gyro_exp34_user17.txt', 'gyro_exp35_user17.txt', 'gyro_exp36_user18.txt', 'gyro_exp37_user18.txt', 'gyro_exp38_user19.txt', 'gyro_exp39_user19.txt', 'gyro_exp40_user20.txt', 'gyro_exp41_user20.txt', 'gyro_exp42_user21.txt', 'gyro_exp43_user21.txt', 'gyro_exp44_user22.txt', 'gyro_exp45_user22.txt', 'gyro_exp46_user23.txt', 'gyro_exp47_user23.txt', 'gyro_exp48_user24.txt', 'gyro_exp49_user24.txt', 'gyro_exp50_user25.txt', 'gyro_exp51_user25.txt', 'gyro_exp52_user26.txt', 'gyro_exp53_user26.txt', 'gyro_exp54_user27.txt', 'gyro_exp55_user27.txt', 'gyro_exp56_user28.txt', 'gyro_exp57_user28.txt', 'gyro_exp58_user29.txt', 'gyro_exp59_user29.txt', 'gyro_exp60_user30.txt', 'gyro_exp61_user30.txt', 'labels.txt']
```

but I want to now group into a indexing list like this,
[image]

how can I realise it?

Comment: What should we do with labels.txt?

Comment: that ist for later use...it contains user id, experiment #, start position, end postion. The start and end positions are the postions in acc and gyro files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` to find out files based out of a pattern from a path then create the required `DataFrame`

```
from glob import glob
import os

exp_path = "Your Path Here"
acc_pattern = "acc_exp*.csv"
gyro_pattern = "gyro_exp*.csv"

acc_files = glob(os.path.join(exp_path,acc_pattern))
gyro_files = glob(os.path.join(exp_path,gyro_pattern))
```

Once you have all the required files , we can create the `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['acc'] = [os.path.basename(x) for x in acc_files]
df['gyro'] = [os.path.basename(x) for x in gyro_files]

df['experiment'] = df['acc'].apply(lambda x:x[7:9])
df['userId'] = df['acc'].apply(lambda x:x[14:16])
```